# Unshifting / Adding to Front of Firebase Object Using AngularFire or Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have an array / object stored on Firebase that I add items to using AngularFire's `$add` function.  `$add` is the equivalent of using `.push` on a regular JavaScript array.  The value you specify is added to the end of the array.

Is there anyway to add my value to the front of this array / object stored on Firebase?  Something that does the same thing as `.unshift` in vanilla JavaScript?

I would prefer an AngularFire solution, but vanilla JavaScript solutions are fine if there isn't one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the data isn't stored in an array (prior to AngularFire 0.8 due out next week), and objects are unsorted in js, there is technically no concept of front/back. This is achieved in Firebase by sorting your data keys or by using priorities. [See ordered data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html) for more on this topic.

In AngularFire, priorities are stored on records as $priority. You can set this value before saving a record to control its sort ordering:

```
var data = $firebase(ref);
data.$on('loaded', function() {
   data['foo'].$priority = 99;
   data.$save('foo');
});
```

To place an item first in the list, you would simply assign it a smaller priority than the other records.

Comment: I knew that Firebase didn't support storing arrays, only objects, but also read that the data gets "ported" to and from arrays if you are working with arrays on the client side.  I was hoping this "porting" process would produce array like indices, but it doesn't sound like this is the case

Comment: Here is a blog on [Array Best Practices](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), covering the Firebase side. In AngularFire, everything is an object until 0.8, when you can call the asArray() function.